# is a rectangle java? hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, xor

Given lengths a,b,c,d. find wether a rectangle can be formed or not? if yes return 1 or else 0.
I am using hashmap and xor operation and i want to know is there anything wrong in my problem solving. it fails for the testcase - a=2,b=3,c=2,d=2(don't know why?)

```
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
    int [] numbers = {A,B,C,D};
    for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++)
    {
        hm.putIfAbsent(numbers[i],hm.getOrDefault(numbers[i],0)+1);
    }
    int res = 0;
    for(int val : hm.values())
    {
        res = res ^ val;
    }
    if(hm.size() == 2 && res == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: For questions like this, you don't need stackoverflow to be honest, all you need is little time and few debugging session of your own written code.

Please debug with your inputs you will have more insight on it.

Comment: Your hashmap is trying to count the incoming numbers. Print the hashmap and look at it because it currently does not count when a number comes in multiple times. You can just use the a `Map.put` method instead of `putIfAbsent`. (That said, I'd strongly suggest thinking about the problem a little more, there are simpler algorithms than what you're doing.)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a `HashMap` of frequencies for each size and then check if all its values equal to `2` (because there are two distinct sizes of rectangle's sides).

That how it might be implemented using Stream API and *collector* `toMap()`:

```
public static int canFormRectangle(int... args) {
    return Arrays.stream(args)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Function.identity(),
            i -> 1,
            Integer::sum
        ))
        .values().stream()
        .allMatch(count -> count == 2)
        ? 1 : 0;
}
```

The same using plain loops. We can dump all values (frequencies of each side) into a list and check if this list is equal to a list `[2,2]`.

```
public static int canFormRectangle(int... args) {
        
    Map<Integer, Integer> countBySide = new HashMap<>();
    
    for (int next: args) countBySide.merge(next, 1, Integer::sum);
    
    return new ArrayList<>(countBySide.values()).equals(List.of(2, 2)) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this help you

```
  private static int rectangleCanBeBuild(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
    hm.put(a, hm.getOrDefault(a, 0) + 1);
    hm.put(b, hm.getOrDefault(b, 0) + 1);
    hm.put(c, hm.getOrDefault(c, 0) + 1);
    hm.put(d, hm.getOrDefault(d, 0) + 1);
    int count = 0;
    for (int key : hm.keySet()) {
       //use xor to find if there are 2 sides with same length
        count ^= hm.get(key);

        }
    return count == 0 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Return 0 for your Input.
Return 1 for

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
int c = 2;
int d = 3;
```